# Center part of the equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have two groups of equation in one row with fixed space between them, and I want to locate the whole expression such that the second part is at the center of the line.

[image]

Could I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You mean you want the box to be lower? Can you supply a Minimal Working Example so that we know what the equation looks like, how the space is defined?

Comment: @Mico Thank you!

Comment: @EladDen I meant horizontal center... Actually I want to define a command accepting 2 arguments, and I want the #2 sitting at the horizontal center.

Comment: Do you actually mean that if the right-hand group of equations is as wide, relatively, as shown in your diagram, the left-hand group shifts left into the margin?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for your reply! The only thing I want is keep the total length, and center the right group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I edited this answer after the OP mentioned in a comment that they want to create a two-argument command, with the second being at the horizontal center.)

You may achieve your formatting objective by placing a copy of the `AAA` formula in a `\phantom` directive to the right of the `BBB` formula. This will guarantee that the `BBB` formula is centered on the line.

For the following screenshot, I've placed the `AAA`, `BBB`, and `\phantom{AAA}` formulas in rectangular boxes, to indicate more clearly where they are located on the line. In your real document, there's no need for the `\boxed` step.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  % equation numbers on left
\usepackage{amsmath}     % for '\boxed' macro
\usepackage{showframe}   % draw framelines to indicate edges of textblock
\begin{document}
\[
\boxed{AAAAAAA}\quad \boxed{BBBBBBBBBBB}\quad \boxed{\phantom{AAAAAAA}}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you need to perform this formatting job repeatedly, it's straightforward to set up a macro to help you to do. E.g., define

```
\newcommand\myjob[2]{#1 \quad #2 \quad \phantom{#1}}
```

in the preamble and write

```
\[
\myjob{AAA}{BBBB}
\]
```

in the body of the document.

Comment: Oh I see how it could be coded into a command. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this slightly differently.
The command `\mathllap` will cause the width of its argument to be
ignored in the centering of a display, instead shifting it left:

```
\[
  \mathllap{AAAAAAAAAAA\quad} BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
\]
```

`\mathllap` may require `\usepackage{mathtools}` (I don't remember),
but as that's an accepted extension to `amsmath` (which it loads),
that shouldn't cause any problems.

One thing to look out for -- if the left-shifted component is
wide enough to stick out into the left margin, it will quite
happily do so, with no warning.